# Do I need to wrap an image in a button to make it clickable?

Tags: html

Why do you have to wrap the image within a button?

```
<button>
   <img/>
</button>
```

Is it good practice to not just make the image clickable but also wrap it in a button?

Comment: @CertainPerformance — That's terrible advice that will create accessibility problems.

Comment: No you don't need to (edit: but it's a good idea to)

Comment: @evolutionxbox — Not doing it creates major accessibility problems. This is (a) just bad business and (b) possibly illegal depending on who you are and the jurisdiction you are operating in

Comment: @Quentin I commented in haste. Need? No. Should? Absolutely.

Comment: @evolutionxbox — Most people would consider fulfiling legal obligations as something they *need* to do.

Comment: @Quentin naaaah... "enterprise"s only support IE users using a trackball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A button is designed to an interactive control, an image is not.

Screen readers will announce a `<button>` as being a button so the user knows they can click on it.

People who navigate using a non-pointing device such as tabbing through the document or (again) using a screen reader will encounter a `<button>` but an `<img>` would be skipped.

Just slapping a click event handler on an image creates major accessibility problems.

Answer (score -1):

Agreed to Screen reader point above. Wont be the best of practices.

You can make use of JS click event to make the image clickable and use css cursor property as pointer to make the image appear clickable on mouse over. Also add an alt text to the image so that it can be identified as an image on screen readers.

Hope that helps better.

Comment: "You can use css pointer events to prevent clicks" — That would have the opposite effect of that desired by the question.

Comment: "You can just have the image as a background of a div and give width and height to that element." — So now instead of having a clickable button containing an image with alt text, you have a clickable div with a *background* (i.e. not content) image and no alt text. That's even worse for accessibility.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Thanks for pointing this out @Quentin. I should have read better.

Comment: I read it as not to make the image clickable. Thats totally my fault. Apologies.

Comment: Re edit: The question indicates the OP knows that already. They are asking if it is good practice to wrap it in a button.